# Prove that $\log_{10}(1-x^{-m}) \geq -2 \cdot x^{-m}$ for $x>2^{1/m}$.

Tags: calculus, number-theory

> Prove that $\log_{10}(1-x^{-m}) \geq -2 \cdot x^{-m}$ where $m,x > 2^{1/m}$.

I was thinking about the analogous property for the base $e$ logarithm for which it is true that $\log(1-x) >-2x$ for $x<1/2$. But how would we prove this statement?

Comment: Let $u=x^{-m}$. $\log_{10}(1-x^{-m})=\log_{10}e\ln(1-u)>\log_{10}e(-2u)>-2u=-2x^{-m}$

Comment: Why do you believe that $\log(1-x)>-2x$ for all $x$.  It simply is untrue.

Comment: @Dr.MV We are working on a bounded interval (such as $(0,0.5)$).

Comment: If that is a condition, I admonish you to explicitly write that in the OP.  Currently, the OP has $x>0$.

Comment: Moreover, for $x\in (0,1/2)$, $1-x^{-m}<0$ and the logarithm is no longer defined on the reals.

Answer (score 1):

> **PRIMER: ELEMENTARY INEQUALITY**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function along with Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x}\tag 1$$
>
> for $x>0$.

---

For $x>0$ and $m>0$, the domain of the function $f(x)=\log_{10}(1-x^{-m})$ is $x>1$.  If in addition, we have $x>2^{1/m}$, then we can write

$$\begin{align}
\log_{10}(1-x^{-m})&=\frac{\log_e (1-x^{-m})}{\log_e(10)} \tag 2\\\\
&\ge \frac{-x^{-m}}{\log_e(10) (1-x^{-m})} \tag 3\\\\
&\ge \frac{-x^{-m}}{\log_e(10) (1-\left(2^{1/m}\right)^{-m})}\\\\
&=\frac{-2x^{-m}}{\log_e(10)}\\\\
&\ge -2x^{-m}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

> In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we made use of the left-hand side inequality in $(1)$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x^{-m}$.

$\log_{10}(1-x^{-m})=\log_{10}e\ln(1-u)>\log_{10}e(-2u)>-2u=-2x^{-m}$

Comment: Why do you believe that $\log(1-x)>-2x$ for all $x$.  It simply is untrue.

Comment: @Dr.MV Well, I just took the OP's inequality

Comment: Yes, but it is invalid as a global bound.